# Present Value of Costs and Benefits

Tags: microeconomics

The state of Minnesota is considering building a highway through undeveloped wilderness. The construction will take 1 year and the construction costs are estimated at 10 million. The annual routine maintenance costs are expected to be 1 million per year. The relevant interest rate is 5%. The expected estimated annual benefits to the public and environment are $2 million per year. Assume an infinite project life.
 is my attempt on the first 3, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.*
I do not understand the parts d and e if anyone could shed some light on it.

PV = Present Value

a. Find the PV of the Costs of this project.

> 10,000,000 + 1/0.05 = 30000000

b. The PV of the benefits of this project.

> 2,000,000/0.05 = 40000000

c. The PV of the Benefits – PV of the Costs.

> Subtract the above we get 10000000

d. Find the annual value of benefits which generates a zero net present value.

e. Assuming an infinite project life, find the increase in annual routine maintenance costs that make the NPV = 0.

Comment: For part (d), you will want to remember that the costs are 10m + 1m/year, so you're trying to find a number that, at a 5% interest rate, will in perpetuity equal that 10m upfront + 1m/year... So it's a number x where (x-1) in perpetuity at a 5% discount rate will equal 10m today, right?

Comment: I havent quite got it but would it be something on the lines of 40,000,000*x-30,000,000 = 0, so therefore the value of x = 0.75?

Comment: So you can pretty much just subtract the annual costs from the annual benefits to get a net annual benefit, right? So it's just (x/yr - 1m/yr)/ 0.05 = 10m, right?

Comment: what do u mean by x/yr? if yr is inifinity does this just mean x?

Comment: No, the formula for the PV of a perpetual annual annuity (or whatever) A is just A/r. Where A is the payment/year. So I'm just saying you're trying to find (x-1m)/0.05=10m. You can subtract the annual costs from the annual benefits to find a net annual benefit, and you just need to compare the present value of that net annual benefit to the upfront cost.

Comment: I see what you mean, so I guess that would make it x = 1050000

Comment: Cool, now use the same understanding for part (e).

Comment: How is A mathematically correct